# AS3 timer works in game

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a countdown timer I made in AS3 the start, stop, and reset works fine in the game.

**Problem**: This Flash app is now inserted into an external virtual-life game as some animated billboard/sign. Each "person" in the game sees the sign but must click the (Flash) button, inside the sign, to start the timer code. Only the person pressing button can see it working. Everyone is given 05:00 minutes to present their offer.

I need everyone in a room to see timer countdown since its for a auction.
Any help I would appreciate it.

This is what I tried to use so far:

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.ui.Mouse;

public class timerClass extends MovieClip 
{
    var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000, 300);
    var i:Number = 300;

    public function timerClass() 
    {
        //# constructor code
        timerTxt.text = String("05:00");

        myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, updateTime);
        myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, TimerComplete);

        startbutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, StartNow);
        pausebutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, PauseNow);
        restartbutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, restartNow);
    }

    private function updateTime(e:TimerEvent)
    {
        i--;
        var totalSeconds:* = i;
        var minutes:* = Math.floor(totalSeconds/60);
        var seconds:* = totalSeconds % 60;

        if(String(minutes).length < 2)
        {
            minutes = "0" + minutes;
            if(String(seconds).length < 2)
            seconds = "0" + seconds;
        }

        timerTxt.text = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    }

    private function TimerComplete(e:TimerEvent)
    {
        messageTxt.text = "PRESENTATION IS NOW OVER"
        timerTxt.text = String("00:00");
    }

    private function StartNow(e:MouseEvent)
    { myTimer.start(); }

    private function PauseNow(e:MouseEvent)
    { myTimer.stop(); }

    private function restartNow(e: MouseEvent): void
    {  
        myTimer.stop();  
        myTimer = new Timer(1000, 300);  
        myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, updateTime);  
        myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, TimerComplete);  
        i = 300;  
        messageTxt.text = ""; 
        timerTxt.text = String("05:00");  
    }


} //#end Class
} //#end Package
```

I need  everyone in a room to see timer countdown since its for a auction
This is what timer should look like, I just need eveyone to see counter at same time once i press start.

https://cldup.com/cds0PwoS5Y.swf

thank you

jln

Comment: Try and show examples of what you've tried.

Comment: _"the problem is that only the person pressing button can see it working"_ so what's the problem? Who else is supposed to see it? What help/advice do you need? Use the [**EDIT**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55282920/edit) button to add any relevant details about your problem.

Comment: I needing everyone in a room in game to see it because it is for a auction

Comment: How are you communicating between multiple clients?  I don't see any networking code in the snippet you've posted.  That part will be relevant to this question, too.

Comment: the game is redlight center its like second life to add the timer you put it on a sign and add flash control to the prop and place the address to where the flash is stored which I use cloud up everyone seems to be able see the timer its just they cant see the time countdown unless they press starti am trying make it so when I press start they see countdown startt

Comment: _"I need everyone in a room to see timer countdown"_ then you shouldn't do a _click-to-start_ logic. Does timer with auto-start work better (others see it already running)? Another idea is to countdown against real-world universal clock (like [**UTC** world clock](https://time.is/UTC)).

Comment: PS: This means (1) Decide when your auction starts _eg:_ 10:15 pm UTC time. **(2)** Use AS3 to get user current clock time, then also get UTC current time (by comparing times, you can get time-zone difference from this). **(3)** Calculate how far user clock time (with UTC difference) is from the UTC auction time. **(4)** Show message "Auction starts in..." with calculations from step-3... Note: When you `URLrequest` the UTC site you should receive the html source code. You want to find `<div id="twd">` and extract time-code text part of that `div`.